# Google Maps API finding area by address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application I want to group items addresses by areas, my items already use Google maps API to choose address and has Lat/Long coordinates. I want to group them by areas automatically.

The example would be
If we have address https://www.google.com/maps/place/Erfurto+g.+1,+Vilnius+04220,+Lietuva/@54.6765968,25.2102183,15.5z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x46dd9398506f84bd:0x6cc62f1d26bc6613

It should automatically be assigned to area, marked here:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lazdynai,+Vilnius,+Lietuva/@54.6702541,25.1870655,14z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x46dd93a6cc53ba05:0x2600d18d4c454331

Areas should be also administered in my application.

As I understand I should store all MultiPolygon coordinates in my back-end, and then use some algorithm to find if the coordinates of address belong to that polygon? Am I right? Or I can fetch that somehow using Google Map API?

Comment: can you be more specific please?  Tell me what you have (in a database?).  Do you have the boundaries of the elderships?  Do you have the location of the markers? ... And tell me where you want these results.  Do you put it in a form and submit the result to the server (database)? ...

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay In database I have items with addresses and location(latitude/longitude) markers already fetched from Maps API. Also I have some elderships, items are assigned to elderships by hand right now. I want to do it automatically. The actual question is: what information additionally should be stored for eldership(maybe polygon coordinates or placeID from Maps API) And how can I determine that item's address belongs to that eldership. I want to use these results in filtering by elderships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some very rough polygons (sorry if I insult anybody from Vilnius :) ), but I think you'll get the idea.

the main method you're looking for is google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation()

So I think this gives you the components you need; the plinciles.  But if there is something specific you want to happen, please tell me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
      height: 400px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
    #my_div {
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>    
  <script>
    // these are very rough estimations of the Elderships of Vilnius
    // please use the correct boundaries
    var polygonData = [
      {name: 'Senamiestis', color: '#ff0000', points: [[54.68256489008578, 25.315074920654297],[54.67631238544733, 25.30803680419922],[54.670555259971174, 25.288639068603516],[54.6752205795425, 25.269927978515625],[54.68812186362444, 25.259113311767578],[54.69506701073871, 25.26529312133789],[54.68832031289468, 25.30099868774414]]},
      {name: 'Rasos', color: '#00ff00', points: [[54.669066215366605, 25.305633544921875],[54.68554193480844, 25.329322814941406],[54.68335879002739, 25.362625122070312],[54.656754688760536, 25.345458984375],[54.610254981579146, 25.328292846679688],[54.60568162741719, 25.308380126953125],[54.65516583289068, 25.29705047607422]]},
      {name: 'Antakalnis', color: '#0000ff', points: [[54.72699938009521, 25.30426025390625],[54.71589532099472, 25.34820556640625],[54.80780860259057, 25.500640869140625],[54.81967870427071, 25.335845947265625],[54.771385204918595, 25.300140380859375]]}
    ];
    var polygons = [];
    var map;
    // random markers. 
    var markerData = [
      [54.75478050308602,25.3638149499893],
      [54.68324427673198,25.27517330646513],
      [54.70583916710748,25.240154385566694],
      [54.68453433466152,25.293562531471235],
      [54.72900384013322,25.330534100532514],
      [54.682078227560325,25.28394949436186],
      [54.65034635955749,25.30793917179106]
    ];
    var markers = [];

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.682611637187925,25.287838697433454),  // Vilnius university
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      // draw the markers
      var markerLocations = toLatLng(markerData);
      for(var i in markerLocations) {
        markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({
          position: markerLocations[i],
          title: i,                           // I'll just set the index as title.
          map: map
        }) );
      }

      // draw the polygons
      for(var j in polygonData) {
        var points = toLatLng(polygonData[j].points);
        polygons[j] = drawPolygon(points, polygonData[j].color, polygonData[j].name);
        // let's see if markers are in this polygon
        var content = '';
        for(var i in markerLocations) {
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(markers[i].position, polygons[j])) {
            // display
            content += '<li>' + markers[i].title + '</li>';
            // I guess what you really want to do, is put this data in an array, or so
          }
        }
        document.getElementById('display-data').innerHTML += '<h3>' + polygonData[j].name + '</h3>' + '<ul>' + content + '</ul><hr/>';
      }
    }

    // takes an array of coordinats, [  [], [], [] ] , and returns Google Maps LatLng objects  
    function toLatLng(point_arrays) {
      var locations = [];
      for(var i in point_arrays) {
        locations.push( new google.maps.LatLng(point_arrays[i][0], point_arrays[i][1]));
      }
      return locations;
    }

    // draws a polygon
    function drawPolygon(points, color, name) {
      if(points.length < 3) {
        return;
      }
      // @see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple
      polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: points,
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        title: name,
        map: map
      });
      return polygon;
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  <style>
    ul, li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    li {
      display: inline;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <div id="display-data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What you could do, is update the markers table in the database; add a field 'eldership'.

You send the data you get from my script to the server, with Ajax, you update the table (= you fill in the id of the eldership in the eldership field of the marker), so you only have to do this once (and you need to update the new markers ...).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more question, where I can find polygons points for specific area? Can't find Google Maps API for that.

Comment: Yeah, Google Maps API doesn't provide them, unfortunately.  As far as I know